# C#. Excel. Need to programmatically reapply a filter on a spreadsheet opened in a console app

Tags: c#, excel, console, autofilter

I have a C# console application that is using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Reference.  The app opens an Excel spreadsheet, writes to it, protects the sheets, saves it, and closes Excel.  This all works.

The spreadsheet has a filter on a section of one sheet.  I need the application to reapply the filter automatically after I write the data.

I tried using `Worksheets.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter()`.  This causes an

> unhandled exception

...it does work in a form however.

```
// The two lines of code below cause the unhandled exception 
// in a console app but not in a form app.
// Refresh the filter programmatically
Excel.Worksheet ceSheet = Globals.xlApp.Worksheets["FAW Summary"];
ceSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter();
```

I also tried using `SendKeys.Send` with an `ApplicationContext` class to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> key combination that does the reapply.  That does not give me an error but it also does not do anything when run in the console app.

```
// Refresh the filter with SendKeys
if (!Globals.interactiveMode) Application.Run(new AGMDataExtractConsoleContext());
```

`AGMDataExtractConsoleContext` is a class of type `ApplicationContext`.  It is supposed to run an application from the console and then pass it keystrokes using `SendKeys.Send`.

Comment: What causes an unhandled exception? What works and doesn't work isn't clear in your post.

Comment: I added more comments to the code block to show where the error occurs.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation, `Worksheets` interface does not have the AutoFilter property. You need to iterate over all `Worksheets` in the `Workbook` and call for [ApplyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.autofilter.applyfilter?view=excel-pia).
Note that if a filter does not exist in the Worksheet, `AutoFilter` will have `null` value.

I created a simple extension for this:

```
public static class WorksheetExtensions
{
    public static void ReapplyFilters(this Sheets sheets)
    {
        if (sheets == null) return;

        var c = sheets.Count;
        for (var i = 1; i <= c; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var sh = sheets[i];
                if (sh.AutoFilter != null)
                    sh.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // some log
            }
        }
    }
}
```